# Revert or remove file with FilePond on REST API with dynamic url for uploaded image

Tags: vuejs2, filepond

This is regarding Filepond & Vue-adapter.

I have a struggle with revert / remove file after it has been uploaded. I run a PHP backend with OpenAPI 3 REST API standard and I need/want to use a dynamic url when revert/delete. I use Vue-adapter.

I use this method to return the uuid after file has been uploade to my example.com/media

```
process: {
  onload: response => {
    return JSON.parse(response)['@id']
},
```

If i use the revert: '/' way to remove, it will send the id as body to /media/, but I need to send it do DELETE /media/uniqueFileId route. I tried some ways with revert and remove but didnt manage to get it to be dynamic. If i use revert as a function, am i supposed to use axios or fetch to make a custom request to my endpoint or is there some other way im missing?

```
revert: (uniqueFileId, load, error) => {
  console.log(uniqueFileId)
  error('problems')
  load()
}
```